# Dart HTTP request to list

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I am trying to convert a JSON array into a Dart List.
So I start with requesting a GET request using the [HTTP](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package.

code:

```dart
      Future getCurrency() async {
        final String url = 'https://xxx/$currency.php';
        Map<String, String> headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          'Charset': 'utf-8'
        };
        Response response = await get(url, headers: headers);
        data = json.decode(response.body);
        print(data);
      }
    
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getCurrency();
}
```

Then here I am stuck. I can't understand really how I can make this.
my JSON:

```
{
  "sell": {
    "value": "0",
    "updated": "e",
    "change": {
      "percentage": "e%",
      "sign": "increased"
    }
  },
  "buy": {
    "value": "e",
    "updated": "e",
    "change": {
      "percentage": "%",
      "sign": "increased"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could share the content of your `data` variable so we can help you with the serialization into an object.

Comment: You can't parse this data to a List. The JSON you sent is an object and with jsonDecode you get a Map<String,dynamic>

Comment: cant i convert a map to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define a response model like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

ResponseModel responseModelFromJson(String str) => ResponseModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String responseModelToJson(ResponseModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ResponseModel {
    ResponseModel({
        this.sell,
        this.buy,
    });

    Buy sell;
    Buy buy;

    factory ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseModel(
        sell: json["sell"] == null ? null : Buy.fromJson(json["sell"]),
        buy: json["buy"] == null ? null : Buy.fromJson(json["buy"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "sell": sell == null ? null : sell.toJson(),
        "buy": buy == null ? null : buy.toJson(),
    };
}

class Buy {
    Buy({
        this.value,
        this.updated,
        this.change,
    });

    String value;
    String updated;
    Change change;

    factory Buy.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Buy(
        value: json["value"] == null ? null : json["value"],
        updated: json["updated"] == null ? null : json["updated"],
        change: json["change"] == null ? null : Change.fromJson(json["change"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "value": value == null ? null : value,
        "updated": updated == null ? null : updated,
        "change": change == null ? null : change.toJson(),
    };
}

class Change {
    Change({
        this.percentage,
        this.sign,
    });

    String percentage;
    String sign;

    factory Change.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Change(
        percentage: json["percentage"] == null ? null : json["percentage"],
        sign: json["sign"] == null ? null : json["sign"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "percentage": percentage == null ? null : percentage,
        "sign": sign == null ? null : sign,
    };
}
```

Then, you need to set your response data in a setState() method. It will look like this:

```
  Future getCurrency() async {
    final String url = 'https://xxx/$currency.php';
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Charset': 'utf-8'
    };
    Response response = await get(url, headers: headers);
    setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
    });

    print(data);
  }
```